# Passing instance variables or query strings around in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In my ActiveAdmin project I have Categories and Products. Each Product has a Category. I am able to save the Product with the associated Category perfectly. I need the ability to add a Product and it's Category but give the user the ability to save as normal or save and add another Product to the same Category. I was thinking I could just pass the Category in a query string but I was getting a double redirect when I tried to override the create method. Any idea how this could be done?

This is what I tried but again caused a redirect error:

```
    def create
      @items_design = ItemsDesign.new(params[:items_design])
      create! do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to  "http://test.******.com:3000/admin/products/1873" }
      end
      super
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason you are getting `Double Redirect` is because when you create an `ItemsDesign` record successfully you have a redirect call but `without a return`. So the next code gets executed which is a call to `super` where there is again a `redirect`call which is causing the error.

You can resolve the `Double Redirect Error` by adding `and return` to the `redirect_to` call as below:

```
    def create
      @items_design = ItemsDesign.new(params[:items_design])
      create! do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to  "http://test.******.com:3000/admin/products/1873" and return }
      end
      super
    end
```

If you are passing `category_id`(replace with appropriate key) as query_string then you can access it in `create` action as `params[:category_id]` and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your user interface, which may help understand your use-case. From my understanding you are having a user fill a form that creates a product, but want the option to add additional products.

Persist Category with category.id as a parameter for the next Product by passing it along the the 'new' Product form.